# Syntax error of missing operator when trying to use Inner Join (Access VBA)

Tags: ms-access, join

I have tried for quite a while now to fix the missing operator error in the below code, which occurred after i added the INNER JOIN.

Any help is appreciated

```
Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", " SELECT PlantCode, PotSize, WeightToWatch, DateWatered, WeightAfter FROM ListWaterings " & _
    " WHERE DateWatered = (SELECT MAX(T1.DateWatered) FROM ListWaterings AS T1 WHERE T1.PlantCode = ListWaterings.PlantCode) " & _
    " INNER JOIN ListPlants ON ListPlants.PlantCode = ListWaterings.PlantCode "
```

The result i am trying to accomplish is the following

Table called ListPlants (simplified)

| PlantCode | PotSize | WeightToWatch |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 18 | 15 | 1200 |
| 19 | 22 | 1450 |

A Table called ListWaterings

| PlantCode | Date Watered | WeightAfter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 18 | 23-03-2022 15:50 | 1250 |
| 19 | 23-03-2022 15:51 | 1500 |
| 18 | 23-03-2021 15:50 | 1300 |
| 19 | 23-03-2021 15:51 | 1550 |

And the result of my query would look like

| PlantCode | DateWatered | WeightAfter | Potsize | WeightToWatch |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18 | 23-03-2022 15:50 | 1250 | 15 | 1200 |
| 19 | 23-03-2022 15:51 | 1500 | 22 | 1450 |

Comment: Get rid of the unpaired ) paren at end of SQL. Shouldn't the outer query be `FROM ListWaterings ... INNER JOIN T2 ON ListWaterings.PlantCode = T2.PlantCode`? Edit question to show sample raw data and desired result as text tables.

Comment: T2.PlantCode doesn't exist in your pseudo t2 table (SELECT MAX(T1.DateWatered) FROM ListWaterings AS T1 WHERE T1.PlantCode = ListWaterings.PlantCode) AS t2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

T2 is just an alias of the scalar value returned by

`(SELECT MAX(T1.DateWatered) FROM ListWaterings AS T1 WHERE T1.PlantCode = ListWaterings.PlantCode)`

You're not referring to this anywhere else so you really don't need it, and certainly not in the ON clause of your JOIN.  I think this is just a typo.  Perhaps what you meant to say is

```
SELECT PlantCode,
    DateWatered,
    WeightAfter
FROM ListWaterings
WHERE DateWatered =
    (SELECT MAX(T1.DateWatered)
    FROM ListWaterings AS T1
    WHERE T1.PlantCode = ListWaterings.PlantCode)
INNER JOIN ListPlants
ON  ListPlants.PlantCode = ListWaterings.PlantCode
```

EDIT I misplaced the WHERE before the JOIN.  And OP added a few more fields to the output so here should be the correct syntax:

```
SELECT ListPlants.PlantCode,
    ListWaterings.[DateWatered],
    ListWaterings.WeightAfter,
    ListPlants.PotSize,
    ListPlants.WeightToWatch
FROM ListPlants
INNER JOIN ListWaterings
ON  ListPlants.PlantCode = ListWaterings.PlantCode
WHERE ListWaterings.[DateWatered]=
    (SELECT MAX(T1.DateWatered)
    FROM ListWaterings AS T1
    WHERE T1.PlantCode = ListWaterings.PlantCode)
```

Comment: Really appreciate your comments and help.
Unfortunately the query still returns a syntax error of missing operator

Comment: Are you saying that if you enter the SQL above directly into the query designer in SQL view and run it you get a missing operator error?  Or does this occur when you are trying to execute the SQL as a string in VBA?  If the latter, please post the code you are using.

Comment: It occurs in both cases. I have updated the post to represent the code and data I am using

Comment: Sorry my acc. is not able to upvote you. Your code works beautifully, and i'll have to spend some time on it to see where i went wrong.

Comment: No worries, my apologies for fouling up the syntax on the first go. Best of luck!